# PHP/Openinviter touch() [function.touch]: Utime failed: Permission denied error

Tags: php, openinviter

I've been using openinviter to import gmail contacts for some time without issue.

However, I have just started getting the above error.

The code around the line is as follows:

if ((!$valid_cache) AND (empty($modified_files)) AND (!$this->settings['hosted'])) touch($this->settings['cookie_path'].'/'.$this->settings['plugins_cache_file']);
                else

The cooie path as set in another file, config.php for those who know openinviter is

"cookie_path"=>'/tmp',

and the plugins_cache_file is

"plugins_cache_file"=>"oi_plugins.php",

I've read elsewhere that this is a permissions issue for the oi_plugins.php file or for the tmp directory.  However,

I cannot find any /tmp directory created in the install and I cannot for that matter find any oi_plugins.php file.

Also, I don't know how I would change permissions on folders or files as the website is hosted remotely.

Has anyone seen or solved this problem before?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions you can provide.

Answer (score 0):

If you can SSH into the server you can run chmod on the file you need to modify permissions on based on the recommendations of the script you are running. Otherwise you could contact your webhost and see if they will change the permissions for you if you do not have SSH or direct access to modify.